# BDD Specflow: Handle DB Objects References

Tags: bdd, specflow

I am new to BDD and Specflow and want to test the following scenarios.

Before I can Test I have to create some data in the database.

- Application User
- NursingHome where I need a reference to the Application User
- Employee where I need a reference to the NursingHome

Then I add a job (from, to) to the employee. When I add a second job some tests should be executed.

Here is my first feature file attempt:

```
Feature: US01_AddEmploymentStatus
    It is not allowed that a employee has two jobs at the same time.
    A job can be closed.
    If a employee gets another job the old one is closed.


Background: 
    Given the following application user
        | FirstName   | LastName | UserName        | Password |
        | Application | User     | ApplicationUser | password |

    Given the following NursingHome
        | Name     | Street           | PostalCode | City       |
        | TestHome | Bahnhofstrasse 1 | 9020       | Klagenfurt |

    Given the following employee
        | FirstName | LastName   |
        | Max       | Mustermann |

Scenario: Employee changes his job.
    Given Max Mustermann has following job
        | From       | To   | State | QualificationId | NursingHomeId |
        | 01.01.2010 | null | 1     | 1               | ?             |
    And he get a new position
        | From       | To   | State | QualificationId | NursingHomeId |
        | 01.01.2014 | null | 1     | 2               | ?             |
    When I add the new postion
    Then the old one should be closed
```

How can I handle the references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Specflow [Cook Book](http://specflowcookbook.com/chapters/linking-table-rows/) the Problem is described and solved (Chapter: Linking table rows). Now I have a glue how to add records to the database within the test, and use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of (assuming I've understood your domain correctly).

The first way is to save the 'old position' information in a variable (either in your steps class, or the [ScenarioContext.Current](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/ScenarioContext.Current) or in a [specific context object](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Context-Injection)) and then in the step `Then the old one should be closed` you use that saved information to look up the state of the 'old position'

The second way (which I prefer) is to make your `Then` step much more explicit. So rewrite it like this:

```
Then the following positions should exist
| From       | To         | State | QualificationId | NursingHomeId |
| 01.01.2010 | 01.01.2014 | 1     | 1               | ?             |
```

I intially had steps which used things like you have in your original example but found this to be restrictive as soon as I wanted a scenario with more than 1 'old position'. Ie what if max has 2 part time jobs and then only one of them is closed when he takes on a third?